# How do i start Ttimer delphi, make the program wait 5 sec

Tags: delphi, timer, wait

how do I start Ttimer?
timer.interval := 5000;

```
lbl.caption:='1'
*wait 5 sec*
lbl.caption:='2'
```

I have ttimer in my form and it is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the timer's Interval property to `5000`. That is the interval in milli-seconds.
- Declare a private field of the form, `FCount` of type `Integer`.
- Attach on OnTimer event handler to the timer:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inc(FCount);
  lbl.Caption := IntToStr(FCount);
end;
```

- When you want to start the timer, initialise `FCount` and set `Timer1.Enabled` to `True`. Set `Timer1.Enabled` to `False` when you want to stop the timer.

I am assuming, based on your now deleted earlier question, that you want the counter to keep ticking.

Timers work by calling their `OnTimer` event every time they tick. Because each tick is a distinct call to the event handler, you have to store any persistent state somewhere other than local variables. That's because local variables only endure for the duration of their owning method. Hence the use of a private field of the form to maintain the count.

Note that a timer does not *make the program wait*. Timers are asynchronous. The program will still be responsive to user input while the timer is active. When the timer expires, the system synthesises a timer message in your message queue. The program does not block on the timer. So your UI elements will, unless you take action otherwise, still be enabled and responsive.

Comment: by what I am actually trying to do is make an infinite loop. but I want the loop to run every... 10min... as 'Refresh' the script will run then it must do nothing for 10min and then run the script again

Comment: Well, don't ever disable the timer. But read my final paragraph one more time. Perhaps timer is not what you need. But it was you that mentioned timers. If you really want to do nothing for 10 minutes then a GUI program seems like the wrong thing to use. Or perhaps you need a thread based timer with a WaitForSingleObject on a cancellation event with a suitable timeout. Very hard to say. I've told you what you need to know about timers because that's what you asked about.

Comment: what would you suggest I use other than timer?(a little bit of topic)

Comment: I won't suggest anything without knowledge of the problem. And yes that's off topic because this was a narrow question about timers that I believe has been answered. Perhaps you need a new question to ask for general advice. Describe the actual problem and do not pre-suppose any solution.

Comment: [the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126082/how-to-make-delphi-wait-30sec-then-continue)